# Can't print in grey scale or fast normal - brother dcp 135-C

Tags: printing, brother

How can I change printer Brother DCP 135 C parameters to print in grey scale or in fast normal mode? Tried everything from changing defaults in CUPS to change it by accessing `defenitions-printers-setings`. Nothing works.

It always overrides my commands and prints in normal color mode. CUPS already as the default settings in fast normal and grey scale but the printer seems to ignore it. Thanks in advance for anyone who spends time by helping me.

Answer (score 0):

from this recent thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354789&highlight=grayscale you need to edit the ppd file that the printer uses; the suggestion is to either have standard or grayscale; or just grayscale setups; the ppd file is usually in usr/share/cups/model and open with gedit or whatever text editor you have installed; if one "changes" the Make & Model settings in the Printer Properties; one can point the CHANGE button to a particular ppd; please post back for more instructions if needed